# MVC4 Actions automatics json deserialization send nulls inside complex object?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a sample jquery call to my controller action working sweet using manual serialization/deserialization. I can send a complex object back and forth nice. But the same code using 'automatic' deserialization sends only the outer part of the object but nulls inside.

Is this a bug?.. too big I think, should I configure something to tell MVC "Please do what was expected"?. Here is my code that works, my code that does not work.

Code That Works: 
Javascript:
    var modelListData = { "listname": "xname", "samplemodels":
        [{ "name": "pepe1" }, { "name": "pepe2" }, { "name": "pepe3" }, { "name": "pepe4" }]};

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:1629/Sample/MyTestMethod5",
    method: 'POST',
    data: { "sampleModelListJson": JSON.stringify(modelListData) },
    success: processGetJSONList,
    error: function (data) { alert("error" + data); }
});
```

Controller Action:

```
    public ActionResult MyTestMethod5(string sampleModelListJson)
    {
        SampleModelList inputModelList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleModelList>(sampleModelListJson);
        SampleModelList outputModelList = new SampleModelList();
        outputModelList.listname = inputModelList.listname + "xxx";
        outputModelList.samplemodels = inputModelList.samplemodels;
        return Json(outputModelList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Code that does not work:

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:1629/Sample/MyTestMethod6",
    method: 'POST',
    data: modelListData,  //reusing previous one
    success: processGetJSONList,
    error: function (data) { alert("error" + data); }
});
```

Controller Action:

```
    public ActionResult MyTestMethod6(SampleModelList sampleModelList)
    {
        SampleModelList outputModelList = new SampleModelList();
        outputModelList.listname = sampleModelList.listname + "xxx";
        outputModelList.samplemodels = sampleModelList.samplemodels;
        return Json(outputModelList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Any answer for this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I have an object which is a list of complex objects. Each item in this list has an array which is always null when using the default mvc4 deserializer (which I think is JavaScriptSerializer). The posted json is always correct and deserializing manually using JavaScriptSerializer or Newtonsoft works fine.